# Vb.Net What is the best way dim a variable

Tags: vb.net

Which is a better method for declaring variables? Are there any efficiency\speed differences?

1.

```
Dim TempArray() As String = New String() {}

TempArray = Regex.Split(RTBMDataStructure.IssuesLog _
.ToString, vbNewLine, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

2.

```
Dim TempArray() As String = Regex.Split(RTBMDataStructure.IssuesLog _
.ToString, vbNewLine, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: The first creates two arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example works correctly but it is logically wrong.
You declare and **INITIALIZE** an empty string array.
This array is never used and the variable that references it will be changed to reference the string array created by the Regex.Split method.
Just a bit of more work for the garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

First one creates an empty array with `new String` which is never used.

You should consider the third option:

```
Dim TempArray() As String

TempArray = Regex.Split(RTBMDataStructure.IssuesLog _
.ToString, vbNewLine, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Or event another one:

```
Dim TempArray() = Regex.Split(RTBMDataStructure.IssuesLog _
.ToString, vbNewLine, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

But choose anyone you like, as there is no different in application execution, etc. I would only suggest being consistent with that chosen one all over the application.

Comment: I like the second one. Types are just noise when you have good names.

Comment: @Pacane: You could even omit the `()` since the `string()` can be inferred from `Regex.Split` (same as `var` in C#).